# KNN : Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20, 499]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Full replit here: https://repl.it/@JacksonEnnis/KNNPercentage

I am trying to use the KNN tool from sci-kit learn to make some predictions.

I have two functions, recurse() and predict(). recurse() is intended to iterate through every single possible combo of features, while predict is supposed to do the actual

```
  def predict(self, data, answers):
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts

    import numpy as np
    if len(data) > 1:

      print("length before transposition {}".format(len(data)))
      #n_data = np.transpose(data)

      #print("length after transposition {}".format(len(n_data)))
      knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
      xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = tts(data, answers)
      print("xTrain data: {}".format(len(xTrain)))
      knn.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
      print(knn.score(xTest, yTest))

  def recurse(self, data):
    self.predict(data, self.y)
    if len(data) > 0:
      self.recurse(self.rLeft(data))
    if len(data) > 1:
      self.recurse(self.rMid(data))
    if len(data) > 2:
      self.recurse(self.rRight(data))
```

However, when I run the program, it states that is has a problem with the train/test line. I have checked the samples in each feature, as well as the answers, and found that they are all the same length, so why this is happening I am unsure.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    best = Config(apple)
  File "/home/runner/Config.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.predict(self.features, self.y)
  File "/home/runner/Config.py", line 45, in predict
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = tts(data, answers)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2096, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 230, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 205, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20, 499]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the repl.it . Could you modify it to recreate your error?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I've been trying different possible solutions. I made a copy and recreated the error https://repl.it/@JacksonEnnis/KNNPercentage-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your axes reversed. The format is that for each of your arrays, `array.shape[0]` must be the same size. I recommend you check out the [scikit docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for more examples.

```py
tts(np.array(data).T, answers)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help, friend.